# Laravel angularJS CORS using barryvdh/laravel-cors

Tags: angularjs, nginx, laravel, cors

It's been six hour and I still don't get the solution for the following problem.

I'am trying to get AngularJS hit my API from different domain. After searching the Internet I found this [package](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-cors) that it said it can "Adds CORS (Cross-Origin Resource Sharing) headers support in your Laravel application"

I followed all the instructions. Set this and that to get it working but still no luck. My server always send me the same following error :

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://lab.laracon/v1/lists?id=123&password=whatever&username=OSVC8HKKcvCFrsqXsMcbOVwVQvOL0wr3. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://lab.angularapi' is therefore not allowed access.

here's my Angular code:

```
var Demo = angular.module( "Demo", [ "ngResource" ] );
Demo.controller(
  "ListController"
  function( $scope, ,$http, $resource ) {

    $http.defaults.useXDomain = true;

     $scope.useResource = function() {
     var Lists = $resource('http://lab.laracon/v1/lists', {
         username: 'OSVC8HKKcvCFrsqXsMcbOVwVQvOL0wr3',
         password: 'whatever'
     });
     Lists.get({
         id: 1
     }, function(data) {
         alert(data.ok);
     });
   };

  }
);
```

Here's my barryvdh laravel-cors config file :

```
'defaults' => array(
        'allow_credentials' => false,
        'allow_origin' => array(),
        'allow_headers' => array(),
        'allow_methods' => array(),
        'expose_headers' => array(),
        'max_age' => 0,
    ),

    'paths' => array(
        '^/v1/' => array(
            'allow_origin' => array('*'),
            // 'allow_headers' => array('Content-Type'),
            'allow_headers' => array('*'),
            'allow_methods' => array('POST', 'PUT', 'GET', 'DELETE', 'OPTIONS'),
            'max_age' => 3600,
        ),
    ),
```

and finally here's my nginx server configuration :

```
location / {

        # URLs to attempt, including pretty ones.
        try_files   $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;

        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' 'http://lab.angularapi';
         add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'false';
         add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' '*';
         add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE';

    }
```

Can anyone help me? what's wrong with my code and configuration ? thanks

Comment: Use postman to test the endpoint independent of angular

Comment: What is the server responding with when you make that request (what headers)? When making CORS requests, the response needs to contain the Access-Control-Allow-<*> headers. Usually when CORS is not working, it's because the response is missing something.

Comment: @shaunhusain everything is running well when i test it with postman. server sent me the JSON data. Status 200 OK.

Comment: @J.Wells that's exactly the problem. I know the server header doesn't contain the Access-Controll_allow. That's why I plug my app with  laravel-cors library. but it seems not working at all. I assume there is a problem with my code, but i can't find one.

Comment: The CORS problem occurs when a request in the browser originates from domain X but goes to domain Y.  The server that responds at server Y must have response headers set to allow the request from domain X or else the browser will stop the actual request (you'll see an OPTIONS request made instead)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally, I found the proper solution for my situation:

1. I completely get rid the barryvdh/laravel-cors
2. Thanks for Dan Horrigan for his tweet

[Simple CORS with laravel](https://twitter.com/dhrrgn/status/288385113442623489)

However, I change the code little bit (I don't really know why $response->headers->set(); not working. Instead, I added this to my controller :

```
public function __construct()
    {
        $this->afterFilter(function(){

            header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');

        });
    }
```

And it works like a boss :)

Comment: It suggests here that you should use the $response->headers->set(); call instead of header(). I don't think using header() is really appropriate in combination with the response objects from Symfony/Laravel. See this article: http://acairns.co.uk/2013/01/routing-and-cors-with-laravel-4/
(But not sure that returning the response is required, as it stop further afterFilters..)

Answer (score 2):

I recently update my [laravel-cors package](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-cors) so you might want to check it again.
But setting the Access-Control-Allow-Origin: * header directly (with the response object) also works, it just doesn't check for allowed hosts, headers and methods etc.

A more Laravel way of setting the header would be to define a [Route filter](http://laravel.com/docs/routing#route-filters) and modify the response there.

```
Route::filter('access-control', function($route, $request, $response)
{
    $response->headers->set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
});
```

Then you can set the afterFilter in your Controller, or attach it to a group of routes in your routes.php file.

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->afterFilter('access-control');
}
```

or apply it when it matches a pattern:

```
Route::when('api/*', 'access-control');
```

I would avoid using the header() function directly. Also, you are setting the headers both in Nginx and in Laravel, one would suffice.